# Twitter Bootstrap Complex Form Layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to build a form that has seven fieldsets - one of them has twenty four input fields (textboxes, checkboxes, etc) and one has a table in which rows are added dynamically. I want to use Twitter Bootstrap to develop the form. Is it good practice to use a grid? Can anyone please point me to a tutorial that has an example of a complex form layout? The examples I see have very few fields in them and the alignment of fields is messed up in my form if I try to extend these examples to contain more fields.

Comment: This would really help, indeed.
If anybody has examples, please share.

Answer (score 5):

You should indeed be able to use Bootstrap's scaffolding grid. Take a look at [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com). It will enable to you to try different Bootstrap elements and form layouts.

There is complex form example here: http://bootply.com/60430